# How to delete a file from the working directory in Julia?

Tags: file, julia, file-management, file-manipulation

How do I delete a file from my current directory in Julia?

Is there a direct function like `file.remove()` in R?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is `rm`. See the Julia in-REPL help (which you access by pressing `?`):

```
help?> rm
search: rm permute! normpath permutedims permutedims! PermutedDimsArray uperm operm gperm isperm powermod VecOrMat invperm invpermute! rem rem2pi argmin argmax promote promote_type promote_rule promote_shape

  rm(path::AbstractString; force::Bool=false, recursive::Bool=false)

  Delete the file, link, or empty directory at the given path. If force=true is passed, a non-existing path is not treated as error. If recursive=true is passed and the path is a directory, then all contents
  are removed recursively.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> mkpath("my/test/dir");

  julia> rm("my", recursive=true)

  julia> rm("this_file_does_not_exist", force=true)

  julia> rm("this_file_does_not_exist")
  ERROR: IOError: unlink: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
  Stacktrace:
  [...]
```

So you can just do `rm(filename)`.